# Trying to load an API and a JS file dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

I am trying to load Skyscanner API dynamically but it doesn't seem to work. I tried every possible way I could think of and all it happens the content disappears.

I tried console.log which gives no results; I tried elements from chrome's developers tools and while all the content's css remains the same, still the content disappears (I thought it could be adding display:none on the html/body sort of). I tried all Google's asynch tricks, yet again blank page. I tried all js plugins for async loading with still the same results.

Skyscanner's API documentation is poor and while they offer a callback it doesn't work the way google's API's callback do.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/7TWYC/

Example with loading API in head section: http://jsfiddle.net/s2HkR/

So how can I load the api on button click or async? Without the file being in the HEAD section. If there is a way to prevent the document.write to make the page blank or any other way. I wouldn't mind using plain js, jQuery or PHP.

**EDIT:**

I've set a bounty to 250 ontop of the 50 I had previously.

Orlando Leite answered a really close idea on how to make this asynch api load although some features doesn't work such as selecting dates and I am not able to set styling.

I am looking for an answer of which I will be able to use all the features so that it works as it would work if it was loading on load.

Here is the updated fiddle by Orlando: http://jsfiddle.net/cxysA/12/

-

**EDIT 2 ON Gijs ANSWER:**

Gijs mentioned two links onto overwriting document.write. That sounds an awesome idea but I think it is not possible to accomplish what I am trying.

I used John's Resig way to prevent document.write of which can be found here: http://ejohn.org/blog/xhtml-documentwrite-and-adsense/

When I used this method, I load the API successfuly but the snippets.js file is not loading at all.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9HX7N/

Comment: It looks like the script loads another script, based on the API key. It's strange, when I click the button, it cleans the body tag o.O

Comment: I love that your handle is jQuerybeast and your rep is 666. Your work here is done.

Comment: @thinkingstiff Passed it! Got any clue on the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For problematic cases like this, you can just overwrite `document.write`. Hacky as hell, but it works and you get to decide where all the content goes. See eg. [this blogpost by John Resig](http://ejohn.org/blog/xhtml-documentwrite-and-adsense/). This ignores IE, but with a bit of work the trick works in IE as well, see eg. [this blogpost](http://paulbakaus.com/2009/02/12/defer-documentwrite/).

So, I'd suggest overwriting `document.write` with your own function, batch up the output where necessary, and put it where you like (eg. in a div at the bottom of your `<body>`'). That should prevent the script from nuking your page's content.

Edit: OK, so I had/took some time to look into this script. For future reference, use something like http://jsbeautifier.org/ to investigate third-party scripts. Much easier to read that way. Fortunately, there is barely any obfuscation/minification at all, and so you have a supplement for their API documentation (which I was unable to find, by the way -- I only found 'code wizards', which I had no interest in).

Here's an almost-working example: http://jsfiddle.net/a8q2s/1/

Here's the steps I took:

1. override `document.write`. This needs to happen **before** you load the initial script. Your replacement function should append their string of code into the DOM. Don't call the old `document.write`, that'll just get you errors and won't do what you want anyway. In this case you're lucky because all the content is in a single `document.write` call (check the source of the initial script). If this weren't the case, you'd have to batch everything up until the HTML they'd given you was valid and/or you were sure there was nothing else coming.
2. load the initial script on the button click with jQuery's `$.getScript` or equivalent. Pass a callback function (I used a named function reference for clarity, but you can inline it if you prefer).
3. Tell Skyscanner to load the module.

Edit #2: Hah, they have an API (`skyscanner.loadAndWait`) for getting a callback once their script has loaded. Using that works:

http://jsfiddle.net/a8q2s/3/

(note: this still seems to use a timeout loop internally)

Comment: I'm trying to sort this out. Seriously if I will be able to figure it out I'll be the happiest man.

Comment: I believe this is not possible. You have to load the api, then load the snippet and then set a callback. If you stop document.write before the snippet, the snippet doesn't load. And vice versa, if you load the snippet first, the page goes blank. Check my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bLmer/

Comment: Basically I am looking for a way that it will allow new document.write's but prevent to clear the page.

Comment: OK, I've added a working example. Doesn't look so hot yet, but I presume that's because your CSS is not applied yet? Also, I've only tested in Chrome so far. YMMV in other browsers, no warranty given nor implied, yada yada.

Comment: I've went through their script with beautifier. I am a pageload performance addict therefore I had this question. Now for your answer, Sir I really don't know how to thank you. For more than a month I've been banging my head on how to solve this. I tried everything that I could think of onto my abilities. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

I belive what you want is it:

```
function loadSkyscanner()
{
    function loaded()
    {
        t.skyscanner.load('snippets', '1', {'nocss' : true});

        var snippet = new t.skyscanner.snippets.SearchPanelControl();
        snippet.setCurrency('GBP');
        snippet.setDeparture('uk');
        snippet.draw(document.getElementById('snippet_searchpanel'));
    }

    var t = document.getElementById('sky_loader').contentWindow;
    var head = t.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.onreadystatechange= function() {
        if(this.readyState == 'complete') loaded();
    }
    script.onload= loaded;
    script.src= 'http://api.skyscanner.net/api.ashx?key=PUT_HERE_YOUR_SKYSCANNER_API_KEY';
    head.appendChild(script);
}

$("button").click(function(e)
{
    loadSkyscanner();
});
```

It's load skyscanner in iframe#sky_loader, after call loaded function to create the SearchPanelControl. But in the end, snippet draws in the main document. It's really a bizarre workaround, but it works.

The only restriction is, you need a iframe. But you can hide it using `display:none`.

[A working example](http://jsfiddle.net/orlleite/cxysA/1/)

**EDIT**

Sorry guy, I didn't see it. Now we can see how awful is skyscanner API. It puts two divs to make the autocomplete, but not relative to the element you call to draw, but the document.
When a script is loaded in a iframe, document is the iframe document.

There is a solution, but I don't recommend, is really a workaround:

```
    function loadSkyscanner()
{
    var t;
    this.skyscanner;
    var iframe = $("<iframe id=\"sky_loader\" src=\"http://fiddle.jshell.net/orlleite/2TqDu/6/show/\"></iframe>");

    function realWorkaround()
    {
        var tbody = t.document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
        var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

        while( tbody.children.length != 0 )
        {
            var temp = tbody.children[0];
            tbody.removeChild( temp );
            body.appendChild( temp );
        }
    }

    function snippetLoaded()
    {
        skyscanner = t.skyscanner;

        var snippet = new skyscanner.snippets.SearchPanelControl();
        snippet.setCurrency('GBP');
        snippet.setDeparture('uk');
        snippet.draw(document.getElementById('snippet_searchpanel'));

        setTimeout( realWorkaround, 2000 );
    }

    var loaded = function()
    {
        console.log( "loaded" );
        t = document.getElementById('sky_loader').contentWindow;

        t.onLoadSnippets( snippetLoaded );
    }

    $("body").append(iframe);
    iframe.load(loaded);
}

$("button").click(function(e)
{
    loadSkyscanner();
});
```

Load a iframe with another html who loads and callback when the snippet is loaded. After loaded create the snippet where you want and after set a timeout because we can't know when the SearchPanelControl is loaded. This `realWorkaround` move the autocomplete divs to the main document.

[You can see a work example here](http://jsfiddle.net/orlleite/cxysA/12/)

[The iframe loaded is this](http://jsfiddle.net/orlleite/2TqDu/6/)

**EDIT**

Fixed the bug you found and updated the link.

the `for` loop has gone and added a while, works better now.

```
    while( tbody.children.length != 0 )
    {
        var temp = tbody.children[0];
        tbody.removeChild( temp );
        body.appendChild( temp );
    }
```

Comment: It kinda seems to be what I was looking for although please note the autocomplete doesn't work? Please check here: http://jsfiddle.net/s2HkR/ This is the default way of loading the API. Note the autocomplete of the search form when you type a city. On your working example, that is being stopped from working. Your idea of doing it though is genius and I don't mind having a iframe hidden. Thanks

Comment: Awesome. Well you don't recommend but I think I haven't got another solution don't I? It's for a dashboard webapp and when their server is laggy, all the dashboard is laggy with it.

Comment: Okay it's been like an hour I'm trying to figure this out. I thought it was a problem on my page but I just figured out that it doesn't work on your example either. Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/orlleite/cxysA/7/show/ If you view your fiddle on its own, it doesn't display anything. (This works though: http://fiddle.jshell.net/orlleite/cxysA/7/show/ ) Thanks once again

Comment: Does it has to be the same domain name? It confusing. Both http://jsfiddle.net/orlleite/cxysA/7/show/ and http://fiddle.jshell.net/orlleite/cxysA/7/show/ have the same source code exactly, but the one works and the other one doesn't. On my case, they are at the same directory but different files

Comment: I get this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'onLoadSnippets' of undefined
loaded

Comment: Take this http://fiddle.jshell.net/orlleite/cxysA/10/ . Just some miss script position by jsfiddle. But in jsfiddle editor, there is no problem in answer example.

Comment: I meant if you change the iFrame source code: http://fiddle.jshell.net/HCrQM/ from fiddle.jshell to jsfiddle.

Comment: I literally copy pasted everything in my page

Comment: yes, both htmls should be the same domain, the main html and the skyscanner loader

Comment: Hi there Orlando. I just noticed that the autocomplete works only for the first city and not for the second and dates. Have you noticed?

Comment: Thanks again sir. Have you tried changing the date though? Wish I could knew how you did it so I wouldn't bother you. Or if it wasn't important, yet again I wouldn't bother you. But if you're not able to select a date, then you can understand its like a waste. Note that if you select a date when the datepicker is in the iframe it works. But after few seconds of loading, when it is shown outside the iframe is not shown. http://fiddle.jshell.net/cxysA/12/show/ Thanks

Comment: I've reset again the bounty to 250. Your answer came really close but at the end I couldn't set any styling and the dates weren't working either. I am looking for something that would work as if it was loading on page load. (Select Dates & Working Airport Autosuggest). Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In the `skyrunner.js` file they are using document.write to make the page blank on load call back... So here are some consequences in your scenario..

1. This is making page blank when you click on button.
2. So, it removes everything from page even 'jQuery.js' that is why call back is not working.. i.e main function is cannot be invoked as this is written using jQuery.
3. And you have missed a target 'div' tag with id = map(according to the code). Actually this is the target where map loads.
4. Another thing i have observed is maps is not actually a div in current context, that is maps api to load.

Here you must go with the Old school approach, That is.. You should include your skyrunner.js file at the top of the head content.

So try downloading that file and include in head tag.

Thanks

Comment: I've noticed. My question is NOT to use the skyscanner.js in the head because sometimes it's laggy, causing my entire webapp to lag.

Comment: Is there any way on earth (PHP, AJAX) to load that on button click? Anything that could say, cancel all document.write page blank?